# Prove that $2^{3k} | {2^{k+1} \choose 2^k} - {2^k \choose 2^{k-1}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Ok, so for this question, I have managed to do basic algebraic manipulations and solved half of the question. I first let $m = 2^{k-1}$, and then after some manipulation we get $$ \frac{2^{2m}}{(2m)!} (2m-1)!! [(2m+1)(2m+3)\ldots (2m+(2m-1)) - (2m-1)(2m-3)\ldots(2m-(2m-1)],$$ where $(2k+1)!! = (2k+1)(2k-1)(2k-3)...(1)$. Essentially, we are left to prove that $2^{3k-1}|A=(2m+1)(2m+3)\ldots (2m+(2m-1)) - (2m-1)(2m-3)\ldots(2m-(2m-1)]$. I am not sure how to prove this step nicely.

Comment: This might be obvious, but have you tried induction? Not that I know how to do it off the top of my head. And is $k$ a nonnegative integer?

Comment: @Mathsexplorer FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%242%5E%7B3k%7D%5Cmid%20%7B2%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%20%5Cchoose%202%5Ek%7D-%7B2%5Ek%20%5Cchoose%202%5E%7Bk-1%7D%7D%24&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [2^{3k} divides difference of binomials but not 2^{3k+1}](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h214716p1187214), plus the problem is basically Q$4$ in [Some nice number theory questions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2113905p15324037). Also, there were other AoPS threads that basically just pointed to other threads, mostly one of these two.

Comment: It appears that this only holds for $k>1$. If $k=1$, we have $\binom{4}{2}-\binom{2}{1} = 6-2=4$, and $8 \nmid 4$. All larger $k$ seem to work after looking at just a few (the numbers get large rapidly).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you! I will use that search in future

Comment: Wow, that AOPS thread makes the math really tough to read! And those are surprisingly long proofs for such a simple-seeming question.